# Query for data to add data to prepareForSegue function

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am attempting to query for data from a Parse table to add it to a prepareForSegue function. But once I go into the newViewController the label is blank. Here's my line of code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "marathonDetail"){

        var upcoming: marathonDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! marathonDetailViewController

        let indexPath = self.marathonsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!



        let currentCell = marathonsTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! marathonTableViewCell

        let marathonEvents = currentCell.marathonName.text


        upcoming.nameMarathon = marathonEvents

        self.marathonsTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        var query = PFQuery(className: "marathons")
        query.whereKey("marathonName", equalTo: marathonEvents!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (marathonPickeds: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                if let marathonPicked = marathonPickeds as? [PFObject]?{
                    for marathonPicked in marathonPickeds!{

                var selectedDescription = marathonPicked.description

                upcoming.marathonDescription = selectedDescription
                         print(selectedDescription)
                    }

                }


            }else {

            print(error)

            }



        }


    }
}
```

The marathonsEvents= currentCell.marathonName.text works well but the marathonDescription is blank.

Any advice? I am using Parse as my backend XCODE 7, and swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing a network call on a background thread so by the time its finished you've already completed the segue. What you probably want to do is:

1. Pull that query logic out into a separate class, get it out of your view controllers.
2. In this instance perform the request in the view controller that is being pushed to. You can start it in `viewWillAppear` and refresh your view when its finished. It looks like it has all the information it needs to perform the request using just the `marathonEvents`.

Comment: how would I refresh the viewController?

Comment: When the request is done you would set the text of the label.

Comment: ok I had to change the line of code var selectedDescription = wildCardPicked.description because it gave me all the information of the row I changed it to var selectedDescription = wildCardPicked.information but now I get an error of "Value type of PFObject has no member 'information'" how can I get the information in the information column?